# How can i get first and last record for all users per day by date range selected

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I would like to get as the title states, A list of all users first and last swipe time per day, for a selected date range(this can be selected by the user). Right now I am returning every time a user swipes.

```
Mike Donati  2019-05-29 09:21:01.673    2019-05-29 09:21:01.673 
Mike Donati  2019-05-29 09:21:10.207    2019-05-29 09:21:10.207
Mike Donati  2019-05-29 09:23:21.737    2019-05-29 09:23:21.737 
Mike Donati  2019-05-29 09:23:30.430    2019-05-29 09:23:30.430 
Mike Donati  2019-05-29 09:33:17.640    2019-05-29 09:33:17.640
Mike Donati  2019-05-29 09:33:21.587    2019-05-29 09:33:21.587 
Mike Donati  2019-05-29 09:36:16.687    2019-05-29 09:36:16.687 
Mike Donati  2019-05-29 09:36:25.083    2019-05-29 09:36:25.083 
Mike Donati  2019-05-29 10:00:30.820    2019-05-29 10:00:30.820 
Mike Donati  2019-05-29 10:01:07.313    2019-05-29 10:01:07.313 
Mike Donati  2019-05-29 10:42:13.057    2019-05-29 10:42:13.057
Mike Donati  2019-05-29 10:42:15.410    2019-05-29 10:42:15.410 
Mike Donati  2019-05-29 16:16:51.493    2019-05-29 16:16:51.493
Mike Donati  2019-05-29 16:16:57.637    2019-05-29 16:16:57.637
Mike Donati  2019-05-30 07:49:33.710    2019-05-30 07:49:33.710
Mike Donati  2019-05-30 07:51:56.003    2019-05-30 07:51:56.003 
Mike Donati  2019-05-30 08:24:29.797    2019-05-30 08:24:29.797 
Mike Donati  2019-05-30 08:24:38.743    2019-05-30 08:24:38.743
```

```
SELECT 
     u.[FirstName] + ' ' + u.[LastName] AS EmployeeName
    ,min(e.LoggedTime) OVER(PARTITION BY e.LoggedTime) as first 
    ,max(e.LoggedTime) OVER(PARTITION BY e.LoggedTime) as last

FROM [ProtegeGX].[dbo].[Users] AS u
LEFT JOIN [ProtegeGXEvents].[dbo].[Events] AS e ON e.RecordIndex1=u.UserID
LEFT JOIN [ProtegeGX].[dbo].[EventTypes] AS et on e.EventTypeID = et.EventTypeID
WHERE  e.LoggedTime Between '2019-05-29'and '2019-05-31' and u.userid = 97
GROUP BY 
    u.[FirstName] + ' ' + u.[LastName]
    ,(e.LoggedTime)
ORDER BY 
    u.[FirstName] + ' ' + u.[LastName]
```

I would like the initial swipe in time and last swipe time per day per user

`user               first swipe             last swipe
Mike Donati  2019-05-29 09:21:01.673   2019-05-29 16:16:57.637 
Mike Donati  2019-05-30 07:49:33.710   2019-05-30 08:24:38.743`

Comment: you need to group by the date without time. for example GROUP BY u.UserID, cast(e.LoggedTime as date). Then you can use min() and max() to get the lowest and highest times of that date per user. Also, don’t group or order by a concatenated string. Just use the ID for grouping and order by max(FirstName) asc, max(LastName) asc or something.

Comment: @BenderBoy Thank you i was missing the cast in the group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using window functions, when you seem to want a simple aggregation?

```
SELECT u.[FirstName] + ' ' + u.[LastName] AS EmployeeName
       min(e.LoggedTime) as first 
       max(e.LoggedTime) as last
FROM [ProtegeGX].[dbo].[Users] u JOIN
     [ProtegeGXEvents].[dbo].[Events] e
     ON e.RecordIndex1 = u.UserID JOIN
     [ProtegeGX].[dbo].[EventTypes] et
     on e.EventTypeID = et.EventTypeID
WHERE e.LoggedTime Between '2019-05-29' AND '2019-05-31' AND
      u.userid = 97
GROUP BY u.[FirstName] + ' ' + u.[LastName];
```

I changed the `JOIN`s to inner joins, because the `WHERE` clause is limiting them anyway.

If you want this *per day*, then:

```
SELECT u.[FirstName] + ' ' + u.[LastName] AS EmployeeName,
       CONVERT(DATE, e.loggedTime) as theday,
       min(e.LoggedTime) as first 
       max(e.LoggedTime) as last
FROM [ProtegeGX].[dbo].[Users] u JOIN
     [ProtegeGXEvents].[dbo].[Events] e
     ON e.RecordIndex1 = u.UserID JOIN
     [ProtegeGX].[dbo].[EventTypes] et
     on e.EventTypeID = et.EventTypeID
WHERE e.LoggedTime Between '2019-05-29' AND '2019-05-31' AND
      u.userid = 97
GROUP BY u.[FirstName] + ' ' + u.[LastName], 
         CONVERT(DATE, e.loggedTime);
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question in that it won’t give the first and last time _per day_.

Comment: @BenderBoy. . . That is a really good observation, so I fixed the answer.